# EF Core 6 : updating object tries to insert FK into to related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For a class with a FK / navigation property, I'm trying to update a FK value. When EF Core `Save` triggers, it tries to insert the related FK, but it already exists.

```
var ticketToSave = await _context.Ticket.FindAsync(ticket.Id); 
ticketToSave.TicketTypeId = 3;
```

As expected, the Change Tracker shows the FK modified.

```
Ticket {Id: 20002} Unchanged
  Id: 20002 PK
  TicketTypeId: 3 FK Originally 1
  TicketType: <not found>
```

The `TicketType` is not found because that `TicketType` has not yet been used by the context.

```
var rowsAffected = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This returns an error. It is trying to insert the `TicketType` into the table even though the record already exists:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TicketType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'TicketType'. The duplicate key value is (3).

I don't want to have to load every possible value for every related property just so I can use the ones that I need.

How do I tell EF Core to save the Ticket FK update to the database, without dealing with the untracked navigation property?

***update

I've made some changes so it shows the new TicketType navigation assigned, but the problem is still that it wants to add the TicketType 3 to the DB because it did not already exist in the Change Tracker.

```
Ticket {Id: 20000} Modified
   Id: 20000 PK
   TicketTypeId: 3 FK Modified Originally 1
   TicketType: {Id: 3}
TicketType {Id: 3} Added
   Id: 3 PK
```

I don't need TicketType 3 added to the database, it already exists.  I just didn't bring all my possible values into the context before assigning the new value.

Comment: `_context.Entry(ticketToSave).State = EntityState.Modified;`?

Comment: You don't need to assign the navigation property when you only set the foreign key id property. And your change tracker shows that it wants to add a new `TicketType` instance, which it shouldn't. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the problem you have.